# Browserify cannot find module source-map

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, browserify

I'm trying to use Browserify to package some JS files together for delivery to the client.  I used `npm install --save-dev browserify` to install the package.  It's giving me the error:

```
Cannot find module 'source-map'
```

I'm running Browserify through a package.json script in a Node.js project.

```
// package.json
{
  // ...
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "cyoagify": "browserify entry.js -o public/js/cyoag.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.15.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.4",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.5",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^13.1.0"
  }
}
```

Command line execution:

```
npm run cyoagify
```

I also tried:

```
browserify entry.js -o public/js/cyoagify.js
```

No dice.  For what it's worth, here's the `entry.js`:

```
// external libraries
require('./js/jquery');
var Handlebars = require('./js/handlebars-v4.0.5');

// precompiled HBS loaders
require('./js/hbs-ified/authoring');
require('./js/hbs-ified/body');
require('./js/hbs-ified/header');
require('./js/hbs-ified/lastPathSnippet');
require('./js/hbs-ified/nodeSnippet');
require('./js/hbs-ified/trailingSnippet');
require('./js/hbs-ified/votification');
require('./js/hbs-ified/votifiedPaths');

// internal libraries
var Builders = require('./js/builders')(Handlebars);
```

Please help!

Edit: I manually did `npm install -g source-map` and it installed, but that did not help.

Update: `source-map` seems to be referenced by a statement `require('source-map')` in Handlebars.  But why can't it be found?